# How to integrate the canonical form of the 2nd order PDE?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Given the 2nd order linear PDE

\begin{align} 
x^2u_{xx}-2xtu_{xt}+t^2u_{tt}+xu_x+tu_t &=0, & &x>0,\ t \in \mathbb{R}  \tag 1 
\end{align}

It is parabolic. I used the following substitutions
\begin{align}
\xi&=xt\\
\eta&=x
\end{align} and
$v(\xi(x, y), \eta(x,y)) = u(x, y)$.

So I got the canonical form
$$\eta^2u_{\eta \eta}+u_{\eta}=0$$

---

***Edited:***

I could let $u_{\eta}=\bar{u}$

So we will have

$$\eta^2 \bar{u}_{\eta}+ \bar{u}=0$$ If we integate we will have as a result $\bar{u}=f(\xi)\sqrt[\eta]{e}$

So we will receive $$u_{\eta}=f(\xi)\sqrt[\eta]{e}$$
Is that right?

Then I should integrate it with respect to $\eta$ twice and get arbitrary functions $f(\xi)$ and $g(\xi)$, but I don't understand how to do it. In examples I've seen the canonical form was
$u_{\xi\eta} = 0$ which gives $u(\xi, \eta) = f(\xi) + g(\eta)$. What is the result of integration for my problem?

Any advice?

Comment: $\xi$ and $\eta$ are real variables?

Comment: @RaulFernandesHorta yes

Comment: @Aruralreader I was thinking the following $$
\eta^2u_{\eta\eta} + u_ \eta = 0\Rightarrow\partial_{\eta}\left(\eta^2\partial_{\eta}+1\right)u =0
$$

so calling $V = \left(\eta^2\partial_{\eta}+1\right)u$ we solve first

$$
\partial_{\eta}V = 0\Rightarrow V(\xi,\eta) = f(\xi)
$$ and i have stuck here

Comment: Your factorization is incorrect.

Comment: @Aruralreader $$\frac{\partial({\eta^2 u_{\eta}+u})}{\partial\eta}=0$$ Integrate: $$\eta^2 u_{\eta}+u=f(\xi)$$  Could you give me some help, please?

Comment: @AthanasiosParaskevopoulos $(\eta^2 u_\eta + u)_\eta = \eta^2 u_{\eta\eta} + 2\eta u_\eta + u_\eta$.

Comment: @Aruralreader does it means my canonical form that is wrong?

Comment: I'm saying your step equating $\eta^2 u_{\eta\eta} + u_\eta$ and $(\eta^2 u_\eta + u)_\eta$ is incorrect.

Comment: @Aruralreader I still don't understand how to solve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\eta^2 u_{\eta\eta} + u_\eta = 0$ then $u_{\eta\eta}/u_\eta + 1/\eta^2 = 0$. A first integration gives $\log (u_\eta/U) - 1/\eta = 0$, where $U$ is a constant of integration, so $u_\eta = U\exp(1/\eta)$. A second integration gives $u = U\int_a^\eta\, \exp(1/\xi)\, d\xi$.

Comment: So what i tried in the edited text is correct!!! Thank you very much